# Automatically unpublish items in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

What is the best way to automatically unpublish items with a specified unpublish date.

I enabled the PublishAgent in the web.config

```
  <agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" method="Run" interval="00:00:30">
    <param desc="source database">master</param>
    <param desc="target database">web</param>
    <param desc="mode (full or incremental)">incremental</param>
    <param desc="languages">en</param>
  </agent>
```

which correctly published items with a publish date in the future but it doesn't work for items that have to be unpublished in the future. I'm using sitecore 6.4

Is there a good way to get the unpublishing to work? I don't want to write custom code to handle it if there is a better out of the box solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afaik there isn't a better out of the box way of doing it...

it's a shame, as it is a missed feature and something you'd (or your users) would expect would work, since you can set up those dates.

and the publishing agent is in my opinion a poor and simple way of doing it (why only an interval, way to uncontrolled... you don't want a publish to go off in the middle of the busiest time on the site).

They need to make the function work automatically or you should be able to setup publishing times, ie. evyer day at 23:30 or something.

So I would say that the only way of controlling it better is to make your own function.

Comment: thanks @Holger. I've been working with sitecore for some time but hoped there is something hidden I didn't know about that could handle this task. It's definitely a shame.

Comment: Yep, this is definitely a missing feature.  But it would rely on something outside the standard ASP.NET model, which is probably why it's missing.  You can set something on a 23h 59m interval which almost accomplishes this.

Comment: Well setting it at 23:59 makes it publish once a day, but the 23:59 is after a recycle (or change of config files). Which means that if you for some reason recycle the app_pool during the day, your publish will either happen in the middle of the day or if you have a nightly publish it wont happen that day.

The default setting for the app_pool is to recycle after 29 hours (which is just strange imo), so I've always changed that to a fixed nightly/morning time.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the code of `PublishAgent`, you'll see that it triggers publishing the usual way, using the standard API for this. This means everything which is possible with normal publishing should also be possible via `PublishAgent`...

I wonder if this can help. There's a separate agent to clean up the Publish queue - `CleanupPublishQueue`. It defaults to keep the last 30 days untouched, but you could have changed it. And as you know, incremental publishing works with publish queue - if there's anything there, incremental publishing picks it. It's just a guess, but is it possible that by the time `PublishAgent` runs the publish queue doesn't contain the record to unpublish the item in question?

You can experiment by setting publish mode to 'smart' in PublishAgent.

Comment: The website is quite big and smart publish takes a while to complete so I don't want to use it. When you set the unpublish date and save an item does it automatically go in the publish queue?

Comment: @marto, Yep, I think so. If smart publish is not an option, try just commenting the CleanupPublishQueue agent and see if it helps...